# laravel authentication: Use combined username

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have to build login in laravel. Normally no problem. But my customer wants to login with some special username. it should be surname-userId.

So there is user-table:

```
id; firstname; lastname; email; ...
1; testuser1; Smith; testuser1.smith@anyprovider.xx;
```

The login name here should be "Smith-1". I just found the solution to override the function username() in LoginController. But in this case i need to combine two table-fields to build the username.

Has anybody done that before?

Comment: you can have one username field and just put that `surname-userId` combination there.

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: Might be able to apply a global scope which adds a concat of lastname + id, and then put that in the `username()` function, not sure if it works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like theHasanov said it is enough to overload the attemptLogin function. The EloquentUserProvider builds the query with given credentials:

```
   /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials)) {
            return;
        }

        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
        $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $query->first();
    }
```

so I just splitted the entered username into two fields and the UserProvider made the rest:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    list($lastname, $id) = explode('-', $credentials[$this->username()]);

    $params = [
        'id' => (int) $id,
        'name' => $lastname,
        'password' => $credentials['password'],
    ];

    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $params, $request->has('remember')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just overload method [attemptLogin](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L73)

Comment: Then I would have all the authentication by myself

Comment: Ok you were right! Overwriting the attemptLogin function was enough. I was thinking to complicated. I will post more detailed answer